# Generic types - type parameter madness

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance, clean-architecture

## Szenario

I am currently encountering the following challenge in a solution that needs high extensibility and I am therefore using many abstract class templates.

- There is a service base `Service` that implements the interface `IService`.
- There are many concrete interfaces `IConcreteService` that inherit from `IService`
- There are many concrete services `ConcreteService` that inherit from `Service` and implement `IConcreteService`.

Now consider a method like `public Result Get(Input input)` whereas both `Result` and `Input` are abstract base classes and like the Services implement many concrete types.

That results in

```
interface IService<TResult, TInput>
    where TResult : Result
    where TInput : Input
{
    public TResult Get(TInput input);
}
```

```
class Service<TResult, TInput> : IService<TResult, TInput>
    where TResult : Result
    where TInput : Input
{ ... }
```

```
interface IConcreteService : IService<ConcreteResult, ConcreteInput> { ... }
```

```
class ConcreteService : Service<ConcreteResult, ConcreteInput>, IConcreteService { ... }
```

**So far so good**

But now `Input` has some generic types as properties

```
abstract class Input<TPropType> where TPropType : PropType
{
    public TPropType Prop { get; set; }
}
```

```
class ConcreteInput : Input<ConcretePropType> { ... }
```

To use the generic input I have to make the following changes

```
interface IService<TResult, TInput, TPropType> // Add template parameter
    where TResult : Result
    where TInput : Input<TPropType>            // Change existing constraint
    where TPropType : PropType                 // Add constraint for new paramter
{
    public TResult Get(TInput input)
}
```

```
abstract class Service<TResult, TInput, TPropType> : IService<TResult, TInput, TPropType>
    where TResult : Result
    where TInput : Input<TPropType>
    where TPropType : PropType
{ ... }
```

```
interface IConcreteService : IService<ConcreteResult, ConcreteInput, ConcretePropType>
{ ... }
```

```
class ConcreteService : Service<ConcreteResult, ConcreteInput, ConcretePropType>, IConcreteService
{ ... }
```

## Question

As you can imagine, with each generic property type, the list of template parameters is getting longer and longer on my services. So my question is, if there is any way or best practice to avoid this before it is getting out of hand?

Also consider that a concrete implementation follows a vertical use case, so use case A has a

- UseCaseAInput with a UseCaseAPropType
- UseCaseAResult
- UseCaseAService

Comment: Yes, just use `object` and accept boxing or at least casting :D. Code can become hard to maintain if you're stepping far too deep in this scrub of constraints and type-params for each and every return and parameter type.
Or at least return just the base type `Result` and not `TResult`, and let the client do a cast.

Comment: What's the benefit of such generic interface? You have it, your abstract class implements it but it's there any client coded against the interface? Maybe drop it and just have these concrete interfaces, not related to reach other

Comment: Also: at least in theory, in a good design, you should not need to know the real type, the interface(s) is/are the contract that should expose all the data and functionality you need in that context.